# What is the workaroud to Types that has a cyclic relationship?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dependencies

I have three self defined data types.

**- struct A**

**- struct B**

**- union U**

And here is how they are related to each other.

```
union U; // This is a forward declaration

struct A{
    U u;
};

struct B{
    A a;
};

union U{
    B b;
    int integer;
};
```

And I end up getting the same type of error

```
error: field 'type_union' has incomplete type 'Union'
```

I've tried various types of forward type declarations. But, one of these types end up being a incomplete type.

There is a cyclic dependency between these types that seems impossible to work.
How can I make them work. OR any other workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you cannot make this work. U literally contains an instance of itself!!

Other than that, the rules are:

```cpp
union U;

struct A{
    U u; ///< this can't work. sizeof U needs to be known!
};
```

```cpp
union U;

struct A{
    U* u; ///< this can work, pointers are of known size!
};
```

Forward declaration only really work in this context, if you are defining a pointer to the unknown object. Your case breaks down horribly here:

```cpp
union U{
    B b; //< B contains A, which contains U, which you are defining!
    int integer;
};
```

In your case you'd have to break one of the dependencies via a pointer & forward declaration. However, something seems a little fishy with your design here? Possibly rethink your design instead?

```cpp
struct A{
    U u; //< either this has to be a pointer
};

struct B{
    A a; //< or this
};

union U{
    B b; //< or this
    int integer;
};
```